# T-SNE code text labelling of the clusters

Tags: r

Im using this code for running t-sne .
I want to do the t-sne on my whole data frame 
So is there way to label my points that are being clustered and as well as label them with different colours to make them visually differentiable  .

These are my samples `CMP_6792"  "CMP_7256"  "CMP_7653"  "GMP_6792"  "GMP_7256"  "GMP_7653"  "HSC_6792" 
  "HSC_7256"  "HSC_7653"  "Mono_6792" "Mono_7256" "Mono_7653" "Gran1"     "Gran2`
I would like to label my points according to the above mentioned sample.

Here is my code

```
file1<- read.csv('PRIMARY_CELL_EPILIST.csv')
head(file1)
names(file1)
class(file1)
dat <- data.frame(file1)
rownames(file1) <- make.names(file1[,1], unique = TRUE)
head(file1)
dim(file1)
data <- file1[,2:15]
head(data)
library(tsne)
tsne1 <- tsne(scale(data), perplexity = 10,max_iter = 300)
plot(tsne1[, 1], tsne1[, 2])

library(ggplot2)
plotdata <- data.frame(tsne_x = tsne1[, 1], tsne_y = tsne1[, 2])
plt1 <- ggplot(plotdata) + geom_point(aes(x = tsne_x, y = tsne_y))
plot(plt1)
```

So any help or suggestion as well as improvement over my code would be highly appreciated .

Comment: When providing example code, it's a good idea to stick with the following guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve
In your case, I would remove all `head`, `names`, `dim`, etc. calls, and provide example data.

Comment: well thank you i just wanted to show if im doing something wrong but thanks for the rectification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will first want to cluster your t-SNE results. The cluster assignments will then serve as color assignment.

```
cl <- cluster::pam( tsne1 )
```

Modify your `plotdata` `data.frame` so that it includes everything (sample names, t-SNE coordinates, cluster assignments):

```
plotdata <- data.frame( tsne_x = tsne1[,1], tsne_y = tsne1[,2], SampleID = v,
    Cluster = cl$clustering )
```

where `v` is the vector of sample names you provided (i.e., `v <- c( "CMP_6792", "CMP_7256", "CMP_7653", ... )`, or `v <- rownames(tsne1)` if it's available).

Finally, adjust your `ggplot` call to access the relevant columns in the `data.frame`:

```
plt1 <- ggplot( plotdata, aes( x = tsne_x, y = tsne_y, color = Cluster ) +
    geom_point() + ggrepel::geom_text_repel( aes( label = SampleID ) )
```

Comment: the samples names are column names ...should i transpose my dataframe? as you wrote v <- rownames(tsne1)

Comment: the samples names are column names ...should i transpose my dataframe? as you wrote v <- rownames(tsne1) I am now able to lalel my sample but is there way to label each cluster differently

Comment: Use `colnames` to retrieve column names from the appropriate `data.frame`. To label individual clusters, you can put together a second `data.frame` that maps clusters to their names / positions, then pass that as the `data` argument to the corresponding `geom` functions. See `medoids` entry under `?pam.object` to get you started on retrieving cluster positions.